# Toggle Visibility based on Dropdown value ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, toggle, state, dropdown

I am trying to toggle the visibility of a Dropdown based on another Dropdown's value. So when the first option is selected, the second dropdown becomes visible below and when that option is no longer selected, the dropdown below vanishes.

Please bear with me as I am still learning. Any advice or help would be appreciated! Here is what I have so far:

```js
const firstOptions = [
  { key: 0, value: 'default', text: '--Select an Option--' },
  { key: 1, value: 'option1', text: 'option1 - when I am selected another shall appear' },
  { key: 2, value: 'option2', text: 'option2' },
  { key: 3, value: 'option3', text: 'option3' },
];

const secondOptions = [
  { key: 0, value: 'default', text: '--Select an Option--' },
  { key: 1, value: 'option1', text: 'option1' },
  { key: 2, value: 'option2', text: 'option2' },
];

class DropdownToggle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: 'default',
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const message = 'You selected ' + this.state.selectedValue;
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: '50px', marginLeft: '50px' }}>
        <Dropdown
          options={firstOptions}
          selection
          value={this.state.selectedValue}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <div style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>
          <Dropdown
            options={secondOptions}
            selection
          />
        </div>
        <p>{message}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do conditional rendering to achieve desired behavior.

**Example**

```
render() {
    const message = 'You selected ' + this.state.selectedValue;
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: '50px', marginLeft: '50px' }}>
        <Dropdown
          options={firstOptions}
          selection
          value={this.state.selectedValue}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        {
          this.state.selectedValue === 'option1' ?
            <div style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>
              <Dropdown
                options={secondOptions}
                selection
              />
            </div>
          : null
        }
        <p>{message}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Update**

Your `handleChange` function is not correct. According to Semantic-UI docs `onChange` fires with 2 parameters. `event` and `data`. If you change your function like below it should work.

> **onChange** *{func}*
>
> Called when the user attempts to change the value.
>
> onChange(event: SyntheticEvent, data: object)
>
> *event* React's original SyntheticEvent.
>
> *data* All props and proposed value.

```
handleChange = (event, data) => {
  console.log(data.value);
  this.setState({selectedValue: data.value});
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work 100%. Am I missing something in the handleChange function so it knows to grab the value from the options array?

Comment: do `console.log(e.target.value)` in handleChange and see if it gives you the correct value

Comment: it comes back as `undefined`.

Comment: what is the package name for the `Dropdown` component? Or is it a custom component that you have created?

Comment: I am using semantic UI. This is the full test I have been doing in code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/8k25z6q128

Comment: @StuffedPoblano updated my answer. please check it out

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and I'm utilising `state` from the context of a `React.FunctionComponent<ITypeProps>` and detecting the current element in a generated `dropdown` to set the `state` (hide/show an element by adding Bootstrap style classes).

For simplicity of logic I am depicting a non-generated dropdown list & it's associated onChange event.

> Hooks let you use React features (like state) from a function — by doing a single function call.

As per [Making Sense of React Hooks](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/making-sense-of-react-hooks-fdbde8803889).

```
const Manager: React.FunctionComponent<ITypeProps> = ({}) => { 
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        showElement: false
    });

    const handleChange = (value) => {
        if (value && (value == 1)
            setState({ ...state, showElement: true });
        else 
            setState({ ...state, showElement: false });
    }

   return 
   <div>
       <select>
          <option value="1" onChange={handleChange}>Item1 + Show Div</option>
          <option value="2" onChange={handleChange}>Item2</option>
          <option value="3" onChange={handleChange}>Item3</option>
       </select>
       <div className={state.showElement ? "d-block" : "d-none"}> Hide / Show me!</div>
   </div>
}
```

What this will do:

- On change of the select dropdown, it will update the state
- If the selected value of the dropdown is "1", the boolean variable `showElement` will be `true`
- If the selected value of the dropdown is anything *but* "1" the boolean variable `showElement` will be false
- On change of the state the component will re-render
- The visibility of the div will change with the state change to have either the style "display: block" or "display: none" as per the Bootstrap shorthand `d-block` and `d-none`.

I spent too long working out this really simple React feature.

**So hopefully this simple example helps someone & saves you some time!**